# Batch extract pdf from emails on Debian in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, grep, offlineimap

**What I'm trying to achieve:** I am trying to send pdf documents to my Remarkable 2 tablet via email.

**How I'm trying to do it:**

1. I set up `rmfakecloud`: a software that runs on your server and emulates the official Remarkable cloud system, so you're in control of your data
2. I set up `rmapi`: a software that allows to interact with `rmfakecloud` and official Remarkable 2 cloud through the command line
3. I set up an email account on gmail tablet@mydomain.com enabling login with less secure apps (i.e.: allow to login without second authentication factor)
4. I wrote (with the help of ChatGPT, I must admit) a short bash script that:

   - Downloads all emails from said account
   - Checks if the sender matches my email account (myself@mydomain.com)
   - Extracts the files from the email, if they are pdf **<--- [this is what doesn't work]**
   - Uploads the files extracted to my tablet's cloud using `rmapi`

**My technical approach:**

```
#!/bin/bash
# The parameters for offlineimap are saved in /root/.offlineimaprc

# Define the senders whose attachments you want to save
SENDERS=("myself@mydomain.com" "myself@myworkdomain.com")

# Define the directory where attachments will be saved
SAVE_DIR="/root/sync/sync"

# Define the command to upload PDFs to reMarkable
RMAPI_CMD="RMAPI_CONFIG=/root/.config/rmapi/rmapi.conf RMAPI_HOST=https://tablet.mydomain.com /root/go/bin/rmapi -ni put"

# Sync emails using offlineimap
offlineimap -o

# Extract PDF attachments and upload to reMarkable
for email in /root/Maildir/\[Gmail\].All\ Mail/new/*; do
  sender=$(grep -E '^From:' "$email" | sed -e 's/^From: //')
  if [[ ${SENDERS[*]} =~ $sender ]]; then
    munpack -q -t "$email" -C "$SAVE_DIR" \
      | grep -E '^Attachment' \
      | sed -e 's/^Attachment //' \
      | while read -r filename; do
        if [[ -f "$SAVE_DIR/$filename" ]]; then
          $RMAPI_CMD "$SAVE_DIR/$filename"
          if [[ -f "$SAVE_DIR/$filename" ]]; then
            rm "$SAVE_DIR/$filename"
          fi
        fi
      done
  fi
done
```

**What went wrong:**

```
root@tabletserver:~$ ./mail.sh
OfflineIMAP 7.3.0
  Licensed under the GNU GPL v2 or any later version (with an OpenSSL exception)
imaplib2 v3.05, Python v3.9.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
Account sync Gmail:
 *** Processing account Gmail
 Establishing connection to imap.gmail.com:993 (Remote)
Folder [Gmail]/All Mail [acc: Gmail]:
 Syncing [Gmail]/All Mail: Gmail -> Maildir
Folder [Gmail]/Drafts [acc: Gmail]:
 Syncing [Gmail]/Drafts: Gmail -> Maildir
Folder [Gmail]/Important [acc: Gmail]:
 Syncing [Gmail]/Important: Gmail -> Maildir
Folder [Gmail]/Sent Mail [acc: Gmail]:
 Syncing [Gmail]/Sent Mail: Gmail -> Maildir
Folder [Gmail]/Spam [acc: Gmail]:
 Syncing [Gmail]/Spam: Gmail -> Maildir
Folder [Gmail]/Starred [acc: Gmail]:
 Syncing [Gmail]/Starred: Gmail -> Maildir
Folder [Gmail]/Trash [acc: Gmail]:
 Syncing [Gmail]/Trash: Gmail -> Maildir
Folder INBOX [acc: Gmail]:
 Syncing INBOX: Gmail -> Maildir
Account sync Gmail:
 *** Finished account 'Gmail' in 0:01
```

**What I understood is going wrong:**

From my understanding, the script manages to download mail from gmail imap server, and manages to upload files to the cloud server if files are provided.

*What doesn't work*, is the extraction of pdf files from the emails. I really don't know what is going wrong, and I don't know what could be an easier approach.

**How I plan to run the script:**

I plan to demonize the script and run it as a `systemd` service

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Yeah there were quotes that were not needed. I have edited the question in the script section and output section. The script doesn't extract pdf files also like this

Comment: Don't use AI to write code. If you don't know enough about programming to write the program yourself, then you certainly don't know enough to debug the garbage generated by an AI.

Comment: Also, shell is almost certainly the wrong language to use for this. Use a language with libraries for manipulating email files - e.g. perl has [Mail::Box](http://perl.overmeer.net/mailbox/) for working with various mailbox formats (Maildir, mbox, etc), and [MIME::Tools](https://metacpan.org/release/MIME-tools) for working with individual messages. Perl also has a variety of modules for interacting directly with imap or pop servers if you'd prefer your script to connect directly instead of using offline imap.

Comment: Python has similar libraries for working with mailbox files, mime, and imap/pop....which should be no surprise as [offlineimap](https://github.com/OfflineIMAP/offlineimap3) is written in python.